# PYTHON SELENIUM COPY A CLASS

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

so is there any way i can copy a class  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc2B4.png)

So as you can see the data-sitekey and i want to copy everythinng after that which is 6Ld_LMAUAAAAAOIqLSy5XY9-DUKLkAgiDpqtTJ9b. IS this possible

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below solution

```
 elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='g-recaptcha']")
    val = elem.get_attribute("data-sitekey")
    print val.text
```